# uibModal nested not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem on modal within a modal. I need to have the second modal to be on top of the first modal but what happens is, the second modal loads at the back of the first modal. Please help. Thank you

snippet for opening the modal.

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: url,
    windowClass : dialog_class,
    backdrop : 'static',
    keyboard : false,
    scope : $scope,
})
```

I am using:

- ui-bootstrap : 2.2.0
- bootstrap 3.3.7
- Angular 1.5.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change fixed for me.

```
.zindex {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works!
Now, how can I close the second dialog without closing the first dialog?

Comment: create two different variable instance for  opening the modal and close it respectively. For firect one `scope.modalInstance1 = $uibModal.open(); `and for second modal `scope.modalInstance2 = $uibModal.open();` and close it on `ng-click ` of modal close button.

Answer (score 1):

Try update css z-index of second modal window.